# How to create a stored procedure to select multiple data and display in one column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

When is the ID is all selected for below table, the result should display as below result

```
+-----------+
| ID | Name |
+-----------+
| 1  |a     |
| 2  |b     |
| 3  |c     |
+-----------+
```

Result:

```
Name
-----
a b c
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "When is the ID is all selected for below table, the result should display as below result". I'm not sure what you're trying to say. 
Your question is also short on detail. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on asking a good question.

Comment: Nothing in this question seems relevant to MVC. I suggest that the MVC tag be removed.

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this. Please refer the link: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Answer (score 1):

please try below:

```
SELECT Name + ' ' as Name
FROM table_name
FOR XML PATH ('')
```

Hope it solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2017 onwards. [String_Agg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(Name,' ') AS Name
FROM table_name
```